# Max value for TTL in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, ttl

What is the maximum value we can assign to TTL ?

In the java driver for cassandra TTL is set as a int. Does that mean it is limited to Integer.MAX (2,147,483,647 secs) ?

Comment: We are talking about how many years? Do you really need somthing bigger than that?

Comment: This is about 68 years ... do you plan Cassandra in production within 68 years? Even if you're right I don't think this problem will be handled by you :-)

Comment: Legacy code is when the programmer die!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The maximum TTL is actually 20 years. From `org.apache.cassandra.db.ExpiringCell`:

```
public static final int MAX_TTL = 20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 20 years in seconds
```

I think this is verified along both the CQL and Thrift query paths.

Comment: For reference `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as seconds is equivalent to 68.0511 years.

Answer (score 1):

20 years max TTL is not correct anymore. As per Cassandra [news](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/NEWS.txt) read this notice:

> PLEASE READ: MAXIMUM TTL EXPIRATION DATE NOTICE (CASSANDRA-14092)

> The maximum expiration timestamp that can be represented by the
> storage engine is 2038-01-19T03:14:06+00:00, which means that inserts
> with TTL thatl expire after this date are not currently supported. By
> default, INSERTS with TTL exceeding the maximum supported date are
> rejected, but it's possible to choose a different  expiration overflow
> policy. See CASSANDRA-14092.txt for more details.
>
> Prior to 3.0.16 (3.0.X) and 3.11.2 (3.11.x) there was no protection
> against INSERTS with TTL expiring after the maximum supported date,
> causing the expiration time field to overflow and the records to
> expire immediately. Clusters in the 2.X and lower series are not
> subject to this when assertions are enabled. Backed up SSTables can be
> potentially recovered and recovery instructions can be found on the
> CASSANDRA-14092.txt file.
>
> If you use or plan to use very large TTLS (10 to 20 years), read
> CASSANDRA-14092.txt for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need this but default TTL is null in Cassandra which means it won't be deleted until you force.

> One very powerful feature that Cassandra provides is the ability to
>   expire data that is no longer needed. This expiration is very flexible
>   and works at the level of individual column values. The time to live
>   (or TTL) is a value that Cassandra stores for each column value to
>   indicate how long to keep the value.
>
> The TTL value defaults to null, meaning that data that is written will
>   not expire.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/cassandra-the-definitive/9781491933657/ch04.html