# How to add 6months and 1 year ttl in Cassandra using java

Tags: java, cassandra

I am storing data in Cassandra DB based on some time intervals like 1hour, 1day, 1week, 1month and 1year, I have to set the `ttl` using those slots like follows

1hour, 1day and 1 week - 14days (1209600 seconds)

1month - 1month+1week ( 3297546 seconds)

1year - 1year+1week (32161752 seconds)

I found it `Using using = QueryBuilder.ttl(int);`

```
session.execute( insert.using(using) ).wasApplied();
```

my doubt is, will it accept those huge values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra support up to 20 years TTL. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846959/max-value-for-ttl-in-cassandra) SO answer. Also, the TTL is visibile in the code, [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b65b28a9e7a3ff049f4e4d0c9d31622b39398145/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/Attributes.java#L47).

I think it's also worth to look on [JIRA ticket 14092](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14092) regarding the max 20 years TTL and the year 2038 bug.